# Mule - exception in Outbound endpoint Message payload is of type: byte[]

Tags: java, https, mule, esb

Hi am youing Https outbound endpoint in mule but am always getting an exception saying that message payload is of type byte[]

INFO  2014-12-31 12:55:02,699 [[collectFlow].connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.12905544'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-12-31 12:55:02,699 [[collectFlow].ScatterGatherWorkManager.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'IPS-HTTPS-TwoWaySSL-Connector.dispatcher.14325410'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
ERROR 2014-12-31 12:55:04,961 [[collectFlow].collectFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : Exception was found for route(s): 0. Message payload is of type: byte[]

### Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Exception stack is:
1. Exception was found for route(s): 0. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.routing.CompositeRoutingException)
  org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy:51 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/routing/CompositeRoutingException.html)

```html
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
            <processor-chain>
                <logger message="Just before calling https" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" doc:name="Property"/>
                <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host:"localhost" port:"8080" path="test" method="POST" connector-ref="IPS-HTTPS-TwoWaySSL-Connector" tracking:enable-default-events="true"  doc:name="HTTPS" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" contentType="text/xml"/>
            </processor-chain>
   <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
     doc:name="Logger In Queue" path="FlowIn"/>
  </scatter-gather>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the aggregation strategy. Since you did not define any custom strategy, Mule uses the default one (and the default aggregator **CollectAllAggregationStrategy** does not handle **byte[]** payloads)

If you do not need any information from the scattered messages, just implement a dummy aggregator strategy to create a mule event:

Flow:

```
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
            <custom-aggregation-strategy class="org.myproject.DummyAggregationStrategy" /> 
            <processor-chain>
                <logger message="Just before calling https" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" doc:name="Property"/>
                <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host:"localhost" port:"8080" path="test" method="POST" connector-ref="IPS-HTTPS-TwoWaySSL-Connector" tracking:enable-default-events="true"  doc:name="HTTPS" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" contentType="text/xml"/>
            </processor-chain>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
                 doc:name="Logger In Queue" path="FlowIn"/>
        </scatter-gather>
```

Strategy Class:

```
public class DummyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    @Override
    public MuleEvent aggregate(AggregationContext context) throws MuleException {
        if(context.collectEventsWithoutExceptions().isEmpty())
            return new DefaultMuleMessage();
        else
            return DefaultMuleEvent.copy(context.collectEventsWithoutExceptions().get(0));
    }
}
```

Check the Scatter-Gather [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scatter-Gather) for more info.

Comment: Hi Nuno when I added a dummy its say payload is of type string